# jQuery UI Position : When window resize

Tags: jquery, user-interface, resize, position

http://jsfiddle.net/jqrmh/

```
$(".one").position({
        "my": "right top",
        "at": "right top",
        "of": $(".main"),
});
```

I need to my box still stay right-top when i resize window...
I try to use  "collision": "fit fit" ..... it not work

http://jsfiddle.net/jqrmh/

(http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138026/Position)

Comment: sorry for bad english :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just re-position on resize:

http://jsfiddle.net/jqrmh/4/

```
function moveit() {
    $(".one").position({
        "my": "right top",
        "at": "right top",
        "of": $(".main"),
        "collision": "fit fit"
    });
}

$(window).resize(function(){
   moveit(); 
});

moveit();
```

Alternatively, assuming there's not some other reason you can't just use css:

Just set the parent `positon:relative` and set the child `position:absolute`.  Then you can just set the child `top:0; right:0`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jqrmh/5/